# Twilio TaskRouter in Django / React JS

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm building a simple contact center app using Twilio.
I'm creating the TaskRouter Worker capability token in my backend like so:
Serializer:

```
class TwilioTokenSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            'token': instance,
        }
```

View:

```
class TwilioWorkerView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TwilioTokenSerializer
    def get_object(self):
        current_user = self.request.user.worker
        worker_sid   = current_user.worker_sid
        # Returns a Twilio Worker token for current agent
        capability = WorkerCapabilityToken(
            account_sid=TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            auth_token=TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
            workspace_sid=TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID,
            worker_sid=worker_sid
        )

        capability.allow_fetch_subresources()
        capability.allow_update_activities()
        capability.allow_update_reservations()
        token = capability.to_jwt()

        token = capability.to_jwt(ttl=28800)
        return token
```

In react:

```
import { Worker } from 'twilio-taskrouter';

componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('https://myURL.com/api/twilio-worker-token')
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data.token)
        const worker = new Worker(res.data.token)
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
```

but I'm getting the 403 web socket error:

```
index.window.js:24 WebSocket connection to 'wss://event-bridge.twilio.com/v1/wschannels?token=(here the token)&closeExistingSessions=false&clientVersion=0.5.2' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
createWebSocket @ index.window.js:24
(anonymous) @ index.window.js:24
index.js:1 WebSocket error occurred:  Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
<computed> @ index.window.js:17
webSocket.onerror @ index.window.js:24
error (async)
createWebSocket @ index.window.js:24
(anonymous) @ index.window.js:24
setTimeout (async)
webSocket.onclose @ index.window.js:24
index.window.js:17 Uncaught n {_errorData: {…}, name: "GATEWAY_CONNECTION_FAILED", message: "Could not connect to Twilio's servers."}
r.emit @ index.window.js:17
(anonymous) @ index.window.js:17
r.emit @ index.window.js:17
webSocket.onerror @ index.window.js:24
error (async)
createWebSocket @ index.window.js:24
(anonymous) @ index.window.js:24
setTimeout (async)
webSocket.onclose @ index.window.js:24
index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at S (index.js:1)
    at V (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at u (index.js:1)
```

The same settings work just fine with html with cdn of taskrouter
the difference between when I'm using cdn and react twilio-taskrouter library is the web socket url, with the later it doesn't include neither the account SID nor the worker SID.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I was using the **wrong token**, with **twilio-taskrouter library**, I was supposed to use the **access token** with **TaskRouter Grant** as opposed to using the **TaskRouter Worker capability token**.

```
class TwilioWorkerView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TwilioTokenSerializer
    def get_object(self):
        current_user   = self.request.user
        username = current_user.username
        agent_sid      = current_user.agent.agent_sid
        access = AccessToken(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_API_KEY, TWILIO_API_SECRET)
        taskrouter_grant = TaskRouterGrant(workspace_sid=TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID, worker_sid=agent_sid, role='worker')
        access.add_grant(taskrouter_grant)
        access.identity = username
        token = access.to_jwt()
        return token
```

Comment: This library is working fine for me. https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-taskrouter

Comment: How did you find this out? The docs are a mess and I cannot find this information.

Comment: Also how do we add capabilities to this token?